# Do dropped mines in BF3 disappear when you die?

Tags: battlefield-3

Probably anything you drop might disappear when you die, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Anti-Tank mines, EOD bots, Mortars, T-UGS and SOFLAM will not disappear upon death.

As of the latest patch, there is a limit of maximum (6) mines per player deployed. Deploying another causes the earliest one in the sequence to disappear.

C4's and Claymores will disappear upon death.

MAVs survive your death, but will always blow up shortly after respawn.

Radio Beacons disappear once you, the deployer, spawn on them. Also, note that as of the latest patch once you deploy a radio beacon, squadmates can no longer spawn on you, only the radio beacon.

Comment: Is SOFLAM not a kit item?If you die someone else can equip it as part of the recon class.

Comment: @Bora It is a kit item, just like every other weapon up there. I'm not sure I understand your comment. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @MrSmooth Ah, I see now, I just didn't know that SOFLAM was a deployable item.

Comment: In my testing, C4 no longer disappears after death. You must be support class to detonate them however. If you change class, they will disappear. I successfully got killed by a tank, and then destroyed said tank with C4 from my spawn point because of this.

Answer (score 6):

Placed Anti Tank mines do **not** disappear according to [this Gamespot thread](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/battlefield-3/show_msgs.php?pid=621026&topic_id=m-1-60844106).  According to thisBF3Blog.com post, though, [claymore mines will disappear](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-claymore/) upon death

Comment: Related to AT mines: I have been able to destroy friendly AT mines by using explosives (tank shells, etc) on them. You only get points for destroying enemy AT mines. Since they are friendly and would not damage your vehicle this is detrimental, so it's better to check the minimap before doing this. Also, IR vision unlock for ground vehicles is helpful for detecting the mines.

Answer (score 1):

SOFLAM does not disappear upon respawn. It stays even if you change class.

Comment: ...then perhaps you might want to delete it :)